# Handling Conditional Processing in Apache Flink's Batch Mode with DataSet Constraints

Tags: java, apache-flink, batch-processing

I utilized Apache Flink for batch mode file processing. Initially, I read a CSV file into a custom object, DataSet<MyObject> readCsvData. Subsequently, I performed various validations on the data and updated the isValid flag in readCsvData. For instance, setting isValid to true for valid records and false for invalid ones.

Now, I aim to use a conditional statement to determine if all CSV file records are valid. However, due to certain limitations:

For Eg.

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
String fileName = myFile.csv
DataSet<MyObject> readCsvData = readAndProcessCsvData(env, fileName);

DataSet<MyObject> validateFile = validateFile(readCsvData);

if(toCheckIsValidFlag){
    //********** process further ***********
    generateAckFile();
}
else
{
    generateNckFile();
}

env.execute();
```

And MyObject is

```
public class MyObject{

    private FileDetails fileDetails;
    private String fileName;
    public boolean isValid ;
    public String invalidReason;

}
```

I'm operating in the execution environment (batch mode), restricting the use of eager functions like .collect() or .count().
Directly setting the flag isn't feasible because custom code executes after the job runs.
Retrieving a MyObject from DataSet is not possible without using operators like .collect() or collector().
Hence, I'm seeking a method to check if all records in readCsvData are valid (readCsvData.isValid == true). Based on this condition, I intend to proceed with further transformations and sink the data, or direct all the data to a file sink.

While used ager functions then showing error.

The exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Job was submitted in detached mode. Results of job execution, such as accumulators, runtime, etc. are not available. Please make sure your program doesn't call an eager execution function [collect, print, printToErr, count].
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to process ALL of the records to determine what your downstream operations will do, you have two choices...

1. Run this as two jobs, where the first job has a counter for # of invalid records, and writes all results to temp storage (ideally in a more efficient format than CSV, e.g. Parquet). Then the second job can check the counter and decide what to do with the data.
2. Buffer all the data, which (with the DataSet API) means using memory by default. Then you can defer the decision of what to do, based on the valid flag for all records. But that obviously creates memory constraints on the size of any one file.

Note that if you only needed to separate the data, you could use the DataStream API with buckets to write valid vs. invalid records to different locations.

Comment: I have tried one approach by sinking the data from a file or database using the first job, and when sourcing the data from the second job, it's obtained in a DataSet/DataSource. Due to this, I'm unable to apply the conditional statement.

I also attempted to execute two statements within a single job, but this resulted in an error stating that multiple jobs are not allowed.

Still we are facing the same issue because data in the DataSet/DataSource so not able to use a conditional statement.

Comment: So were neither of the two options I mentioned viable for you? If so, why not?